# How can I make this css border property one liner?

Tags: css, sass

I have this working css but I like to make it into one line, is it possible?

```
border-radius: 0;
border-color: #ccc;
border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
border-style: none none solid none;
```

Comment: border : 2px solid #ccc;  this will make it in single line but the 2px width will add for top bottom and both side ., if you want to have width only for bottom you have to use it separate declaration as border-width-bottom : 2px;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This short article covers the various bits of CSS shorthand you'll encounter in your day to day work.

https://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/CSS_shorthand_reference

**Border**

`border` allows you to set `border` `width`, `style` and, `color`.

**UPDATE:**

As @torazaburo pointed out it actually requires `border: 0 none #ccc` for it to be correct as well as adding `border-radius: 0` as it's not part of the border shorthand.

```
#example {
  border: 0 none #ccc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

If it's not an issue that the following could take non-bottom border width and style from other rules in the cascade then this should be fine:

```
#example {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

Produces the same CSS that you're wanting:

https://jsfiddle.net/betg5xue/5/

Answer (score 2):

If you simply try to do

```
border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
```

it could possibly take non-bottom border width and style from other rules in the cascade. If that's not an issue, then the above would be fine.

The only reliable way that is identical to what you proposed involves three lines, there's no way around it:

```
#example {
  border: 0 none #ccc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, it is necessary to repeat the `#ccc` in the `border-bottom` property because if omitted it does not take the value from the cascade; instead it takes `currentColor`. It is necessary to specify `border-radius` as a separate property because it is not part of the `border` shorthand.